# Purpose of validation data NN

Tags: neural-network

Aside from using validation data to tune the hyperparameters is there any other benefit to including validation data to the model?

All I ever read about is it being used to tune hyperparameters and check for overfitting. Is the checking for overfitting separate from tuning the hyperparameters?

Training: Tune the parameters (weights and biases)
Validation: Tune hyperparameters
Test: Evaluate the model

So, if we are NOT tuning the hyperparameters, the validation set is pointless?

Comment: `Is the checking for overfitting separate from tuning the hyperparameters` yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use both validation set and test set?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18339/why-use-both-validation-set-and-test-set)

Comment: So if I am correct, validation set is ONLY used to set the hyperparameters. IF the hyperparameters have been set empirically, there is no need for it?

Comment: Ah never mind, I guess overfitting is really a problem with the length in training time? Thus, the validation set provides a measure to if we have starting fitting too well. I get it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea of a validation set is that the model does not know about this data, so you can get an unbiased estimation of the model's performance. Then based on this unbiased estimation you find the best parameters for the model. The problem is, that finding the hyperparameters is in itself a way of training your model. So with optimized hyperparameters the model starts to overfit on the validation set. That is why to check the real accuracy of the model you actually need a different part of data, that your model never saw. This is the testing part of data.

Therefore in your case, when you do not have any hyperparameters, you can just use the division on train and test.

If you want a higher accuracy of estimating your model's accuracy than it is better to use Cross Validation instead of just dividing on train and test. Neural networks usually do not do full cross validation because it means increasing the computation time several times (5 for 5-fold cross validation).

With hyperparameters the ideal way is to do a double cross validation. One for validation set and one for test set. This is too expensive computationally so it is only used on very simple models, like a ridge regression.

Also very few models, that I know of, do not have hyperparameters. And usually those that do not have hyperparameters perform poorly compared to the ones that have. Ridge regression is often better than linear regression. Neural networks with variable number of layers perform better than fully automated neural networks.